# Setting multiple id in option

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello i am making option to choose among few ips and as its auto generated with php all `option id="userip"` is same. I face problem when i choose 2nd, 3rd or even 4th it auto take first ip which is `127.0.0.1` even if in option i choose ip `127.0.2.2` or any other.

I wanted to solve this so wanted to know best way to do it.

```
<div class="row"> Choose ip:
    <select name="search"> 
         <option id="userip">127.0.0.1</option>
         <option id="userip">127.0.2.2</option>
         <option id="userip">127.3.3.3</option>
         <option id="userip">127.0.4.4</option>
    </select>
    <input class="adm" type="button" onclick="getuser()" value="Get Result">
</div>
```

Here is my js

```
function getuser() {
    var e = $("#userip").val();
    $("#showuser").html("")
    $.ajax({
        url: "adm.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "action=getuser&search="+e+"",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e) {
           // do something
        },
        error: function () {}
    })
}
```

Comment: You cannot use the same `id` on multiple elements on the same page. The `id` attribute is supposed to remain unique. You should give them different `id`s, use `class` instead (which doesn't have to be unique), or a combination of the two.

Comment: The problem is clearly with the php that generates the options, so you should show that

Comment: `id` should be unique, can you change the PHP script?

Comment: Thanks i will think other way then :) @ajp15243

Comment: Its ok i just wanted to know if its possible @user574632 but thanks i will do it in other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ID must be unique at the page:

```
<div class="row"> Choose ip:
    <select name="search" id="userip"> 
         <option>127.0.0.1</option>
         <option>127.0.2.2</option>
         <option>127.3.3.3</option>
         <option>127.0.4.4</option>
    </select>
    <input class="adm" type="button" onclick="getuser()" value="Get Result">
</div>
```

And for select option value, use child selector. See jquery [official documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)

```
var e = $("#userip option:selected").text();
```

Or

```
var e = $("#userip").val();
```

Comment: `$("#userip").val();`

Comment: corrected: when we use option:selected - value will get by text() function (not val())

Comment: I just replace **<select name="search" id="userip">** and all is good

Answer (score -1):

just fetch the value of the search field. you can also use the callback onchange.

HTML code

```
<div class="row"> Choose ip:
<select name="search" id="search" onchange="getuser()"> 
    <option id="userip">127.0.0.1</option>
     <option id="userip">127.0.2.2</option>
     <option id="userip">127.3.3.3</option>
     <option id="userip">127.0.4.4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS code

```
function getuser() {
var e = $("#search").val();
$("#showuser").html("")
$.ajax({
    url: "adm.php",
    type: "post",
    data: "action=getuser&search="+e+"",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (e) {
       // do something
    },
    error: function () {}
})
```

}

Comment: When using onclick or onchange it is no difference, because "id" is the unique element

Comment: just for the sake of removing the extra button. no button is required when you use a dropdown